# How to render the response of api using the (Promise all)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I create sample project CMS then now I have problem fetching the data.  I used the **Promise.all** of javascript, now i got error, the question is how to render the setState into the JSX. Thank.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: renderMission is not defined

**This is the code:**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    }

}

componentWillMount() {

    Promise.all([
        axios.get('/api/mission'),
        axios.get('/api/store')
    ]).then(response => {


        const [storesApiRes, missionsApiRes] = response;
        this.setState({storesApiRes,missionsApiRes}, () => {
            console.log(missionsApiRes);
        });

    })
}

renderMission() {
   return this.state.missionsApiRes.map(mission => 
        <div>{mission.content}</div>
    )
}
```

**In my JSX**

```
<div className="container">
     {renderMission()}
 </div>
```

My Console Log
[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `this` to access functions of same component.

```
<div className="container">
 {this.renderMission()}
</div>
```

Comment: this error is different, you have to update the state properly

Comment: I already run watch it. but still got error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: what is your state variable ?

Comment: define state like this `this.state = {
missionsApiRes:[],
storesApiRes : []
    }`

Comment: after i define it?

Comment: then you won't get `map` of undefined error. if you are updating the arrays correctly. are you getting this data in  `console.log(missionsApiRes)` ?

Comment: pass props in constructor like this `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
missionsApiRes:[],
storesApiRes : []
    }

}`

Comment: i already put the state inside of constructor. how to pass the response

Comment: usign this.setState , you are doing that. are you getting data in 
 console.log(missionsApiRes) ?

Comment: yes... i got the data from api. but when i render it i got error.

Comment: are you getting array or what is the type of data you are getting ?

Comment: I add image on top

Comment: put <div>{mission.content_title}</div> what you are getting?

Comment: I think he just needs to parse the response data, they are strings, not json objects... (at least in the image it seems like this), so try "JSON.parse(response)" without the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

Update your JSX to include `this`

```
<div className="container">
  {this.renderMission()}
</div>
```

And update your default state, because the page will render **before** the promises have resolved. So your javascript file should look like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {

  }

}

componentWillMount() {

  this.setState({
    missionsApiRes: []
  });

  Promise.all([
    axios.get('/api/mission'),
    axios.get('/api/store')
  ]).then(response => {
    const [storesApiRes, missionsApiRes] = response;
    this.setState({storesApiRes,missionsApiRes}, () => {
        console.log(missionsApiRes);
    });
  })
}

renderMission() {
  return this.state.missionsApiRes.map(mission => 
    <div>{mission.content}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, George it gives same error.Uncaught TypeError: this.state.missionsApiRes.map is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I’ve updated my answer. Please try that instead